# Errors while generation gpg keys, The trustdb is corrupted

Tags: gnupg

This is the log

`gpg: lookup_hashtable failed: eof
    gpg: lookup_hashtable failed: eof
    gpg: upd_hashtable: read failed: eof
    gpg: trust record 1, type 12: write failed: eof
    gpg: Error: The trustdb is corrupted.
    gpg: You may try to re-create the trustdb using the commands:
    gpg:   cd ~/.gnupg
    gpg:   gpg2 --export-ownertrust > otrust.tmp
    gpg:   rm trustdb.gpg
    gpg:   gpg2 --import-ownertrust < otrust.tmp
    gpg: If that does not work, please consult the manual`

I tried regenerating the trustdb using the above instructions but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you find solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes, tried to do the same being su.
It worked.

Comment: Dublicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/334280/89346